# How to display shape data on the document itself

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I updated a sketch and I added data to shapes.

Is there a way to display this data next to the shapes easily? So it would show up when I print it? Or do I need to do it manually by adding text boxes or callouts?

Answer (score 9):

You could try using text fields.

For example: below is a shape with some shape data

[image]

Edit the text of the shape.

[image]

And from the ribbon choose **Insert/Field**

[image]

And then Under Shape Data, select the property you want

[image]

Now the shape's text will contain the data

[image]

Afterwards, any change to the data will change the shape text

[image]

Aftwerwards you can displace the Text box from the shape it is attached to so that the text appears next to the shape.

Answer (score 5):

This exactly what data graphics are for. Once you have your data defined, use menu Data -> Data Graphics